Need Excel formula help to return a correct Position where a value sits in an array of numbers



Group
Max Length




1
45


2
61


3
120


4
150



I have this small table
I am trying to look up on this table where the value of 70 falls. (so does it fall between 45-61 or 61 to 120 etc)
For context - I have a parcel that measures 70cm. It cannot be assigned to Group 2 as 61cm is its max max length
It needs to be allocated to Group 3
Google says to use MATCH with -1
MATCH(70, A1:A4, -1)
When I do I get an #N/A and google suggests this is due to Ascending/Descending order
But the order of "Group" is how it needs to look
When I try
MATCH(70, A1:A4,1) I get Group 2 - which is incorrect
RESULT needs to be
70= 3
Any advice is appreciated
Thanks

Thanks - that helped me to understand that logic. I just cannot figure out how to get it to say Group/Line 3 (120) as its not correct sitting in line 2 (61)

Use XMATCH if available =IFNA(XMATCH(70,A1:A5,1),4)

Edited in an IFNA. Older Excel =IFNA(MATCH(TRUE,(B2:B5>=70),),4)

The max boundary value for each group

P,b - XMATCH for the win. Is working. Had to amend a few things but its showing whats needed and when I amend my 70 to other values, its producing the line I expected. Thanks

@P.b It should be an exact match (0): =IFNA(MATCH(TRUE,B$2:B$5>=70,0),ROWS(B$2:B$5)+1).

@VBasic2008 It is, I typed a comma, but no zero, which is equal to zero (exact match). Without the comma it would be approximate. Nice addition using rows +1 to make it somewhat dynamic

@P.b Wow, I never knew about that. Sorry.

=XLOOKUP(D2,{45,61,120,150},{1,2,3,4},4,1,2) with input in D2 XLOOKUP function - Microsoft Support

If you have one cell, or you need to drag this formula down or Flash Fill a column in a defined data Table, this formula will work:
=XLOOKUP(K9,$H$4:$H$7,$G$4:$G$7,"Bigger than 150",1)
K9 is the single sell value in question.
The lookup array is the Max Length data.
The Return Array is the Group Numbers.
If the size is larger than 150, this is stated - in the 'if not found' part of the formula.
The match mode is 'exact match or next larger item'.
The 'search mode' is not specified, but by default is first to last.
The last 3 parts of the formula are optional, but, in this example the first 2 of these do need to be specified.
